# Stream is receiving on YouTube server but can't play it

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, android-ffmpeg

I'm using [yesea](https://github.com/begeekmyfriend/yasea/) repository to live stream to YouTube. Whenever I publish the stream, from YouTube Live Control Room I can see that the stream is LIVE.

[image]

However, when I try to play/watch the live video. This happens

[image]

I have enabled `DVR` and `RecordFromStart` but when I try to play the video after I finish the stream, this happens:

[image]

I don't understand what's the problem, since the streaming `status` is `good`. Why the video can't be played? On the `logcat` I'm receiving a-lot of logs that that much audio is packed and sent... But there isn't any log for video, is that normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is viewed 51 times and no one has answered it, since, I have solved the problem, I'm answering in a hope that it will be helpful for someone.

> On the Logcat I'm receiving a lot of logs that that much audio is packed and sent... But there isn't any log for video, is that normal?

Yes, this is normal. They don't have `Log` for video encoding.

I wasn't able to play the video because of 2 reasons.

1. I have set the mode private.
2. My connection speed was too slow, it couldn't send video encoded pieces to YouTube server.